# How to know whether i am overfitting/underfitting my data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

So i have to build a regression model to predict wine quality based on 11 inputs. Currently i am evaluating the Mean Squared Error, Mean absolute error and R2 scores of various algorithms. I want to make a decision on which algorithm to use, but before i do, i want to make sure my data is not being overfitted/underfitted. Below is the link to the dataset i use (its a bit different but the data is exactly the same) as well as my entire code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Data:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/

Also, the kagggle link where i copied most of my code from:
https://www.kaggle.com/jhansia/regression-models-analysis-on-the-wine-quality

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

wine = pd.read_csv('wineQualityReds.csv', usecols=lambda x: 'Unnamed' not in x,)

wine.head()

y = wine.quality
X = wine.drop('quality',axis = 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(X,y,random_state = 0, stratify = y)

from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(train_x)
train_x_scaled = scaler.transform(train_x)

test_x_scaled = scaler.transform(test_x)

from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

models = []
models.append(('DecisionTree', DecisionTreeRegressor()))
models.append(('RandomForest', RandomForestRegressor()))
models.append(('GradienBoost', GradientBoostingRegressor()))
models.append(('SVR', SVR()))
names = []

for name,model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5,random_state=2)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model,train_x_scaled,train_y, cv= kfold, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error')
    names.append(name)
    msg  = "%s: %f" % (name, -1*(cv_results).mean())
    print(msg)


model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(train_x_scaled,train_y)
pred_y = model.predict(test_x_scaled)

from sklearn import metrics

print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(test_y, pred_y))  
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(test_y, pred_y))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_y, pred_y)))
print('R2:', metrics.r2_score(test_y, pred_y))
```

Comment: If you are not getting good accuracy on the training set, then it would be underfitting. And if you get good accuracy on training set, but not on unseen/new test set, then it could be overfitting. This is one of the simple way to check for underfitting and overfitting. So check the accuracy of your model on train set and test set.

Comment: better place to ask: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry, i thought since someone might be able to indicate some code that i could use, i would ask it here. I understand the concepts, but dont know what code to use that would help me in visualizing underfitting/overfitting

Comment: Check this link https://web.archive.org/web/20170815214245/https://www.autonlab.org/_media/tutorials/overfit10.pdf

Comment: @vbrises your comment is not only excellent advice, it is my understanding this is one of the primary reasons for splitting the data into training and test data sets in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross validation on the data sets to find whether it is over fitting or under fitting.